# cannot source bash profile in csh

Tags: linux, ksh, csh, bash

I tried googling this for a while before asking my question....i have the below oracle user when it tried to login (su - oracle) seems like the .bash_profile is not getting picked up...i am testing that using a alias cmd that i put in there called "l" which does "ls -ltr"...

Funny thing is when i go to corn shell(KSH)...and echo out my shell i still get CSH as my default shell....while on my default shell(CSH) i cannot source my .bash_profile.... what am i doing wrong here ??...the profile gets created by default when we create a new user using "useradd" cmd....

```
srv248:/oracle# su - oracle
srv248:/oracle/TEST> cat /etc/passwd | grep oracle
oracle:x:110:501:Oracle user:/oracle/TEST:/bin/csh
srv248:/oracle/TEST>
srv248:/oracle/TEST> cat .bash_profile
PATH=/usr/sbin:$PATH:/sbin:/bin:/sbin
stty erase ^?
umask 022
PS1=`tput smso``hostname | cut -d. -f1``tput rmso`":"'$PWD'"> "
alias p='pwd'
alias l='ls -ltr'
srv248:/oracle/TEST> l
l: Command not found.
srv248:/oracle/TEST> source .bash_profile
set: Variable name must begin with a letter.
srv248:/oracle/TEST>
srv248:/oracle/TEST> echo $SHELL
/bin/csh
srv248:/oracle/TEST>
srv248:/oracle/TEST> ksh
$
$ . ./.bash_profile


Value of TERM has been set to "xterm".
srv248:/oracle/TEST>
srv248:/oracle/TEST> l
total 68
drwx------ 2 oracle dba 16384 Mar 30 20:39 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x 2 oracle dba  4096 Aug 18 16:20 10g
drwxr-xr-x 2 oracle dba  4096 Aug 18 16:21 control
drwxr-xr-x 3 oracle dba  4096 Aug 18 18:04 data
srv248:/oracle/TEST>
srv248:/oracle/TEST> echo $SHELL
/bin/csh
srv248:/oracle/TEST>
```

Comment: `csh` is not `bash`. You cannot expect `csh` to read a `bash` initialization file. If you want `bash` run `bash`.

Comment: If you want to change your user's default shell look at `chsh` or similar tools.

Comment: If you must get the environment settings in the bash script, and then want to run C shell, then you can play with typing `bash` at the C shell prompt, followed by `. the_bash_profile` (or `source the_bash_profile`) to read the environment settings, followed by `exec csh` to get back to the C shell.  You might need `bash -l` to get a 'login shell', or you might not.  This might get you around the problems, but it depends on what your C shell startup scripts do too.

Answer (score 0):

this was my bad i guess...figured out what was wrong with it...

I am using csh as the user shell but asking it to read .bash_profile...which does not work....once i changed my user's shell back to /bin/bash in /etc/passwd it worked...